# Chart COUNT Query C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Kinda new to C#, I'm a bit confused with this issue I encountered in my codes for a school assignment. Trying to make a Room Activity chart in a winform for a school project where the SQL COUNT query I input counts the rows that have the value 'Room Activity' under the Event column but for some odd reason, I receive an ArgumentException wasn't handled error that tells me Column with name 'Event' was not found.

What am I doing wrong with my code?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;




namespace Database_Chart_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database_Chart_test.Properties.Settings.LibrarySystemConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Activitychart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void RoomChart()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log WHERE Event = 'Room Activity'", con);
            adapt.Fill(ds);
            Activitychart.DataSource = ds;

            Activitychart.Series["WithActivity"].XValueMember = "Event";
            Activitychart.Series["WithActivity"].YValueMembers = "Event";
            con.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'librarySystemDataSet1.RoomsBooking' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.roomsBookingTableAdapter.Fill(this.librarySystemDataSet1.RoomsBooking);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'librarySystemDataSet.Log' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.logTableAdapter.Fill(this.librarySystemDataSet.Log);
            RoomChart();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the `Event` column exists on the `Log` table? Can you share what that table looks like?

Comment: The `Event` column does exist in the Log table. Though despite that it tells me it does not exist. 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log] (
    [Id]        INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Event]     VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [EndTime]   DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [User]      VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log WHERE Event = 'Room Activity'` executed, it will return a table with 1 column and 1 row (the count number).

Query result:

[image]

So the cause of the `ArgumentException` is that there is no column named `Event` in `ds.Tables[0]`.

If you want to get the `count`, just call [`ExecuteScalar Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
{
    string strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log WHERE Event = 'Room Activity'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);

    conn.Open();
    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    // add data point
    Activitychart.Series["WithActivity"].Points.AddXY("Event", count);
    Console.WriteLine("The count is {0}", count);
}
```

In addition, according to the code you provided, you are trying to use `Event`(a string) as `YValueMembers`. This does not seem reasonable. Generally, `YValueMembers` should be of numeric type.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much for explaining what I was doing wrong what was actually happening inside the code.
<br/>
Though I'm curious, is it possible to have functions to filter out the ds.Table data?

Comment: @Spartan889 Well, does this: [DataView.RowFilter Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=net-5.0) help you?